# What is the approximate distribution of the distance between gas stations along a highway?

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution, operations-research

Thinking it should be exponential, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Is there some theoretical motivation for an exponential distribution or even any particular distribution at all? It makes the most sense to me to put them every $x$-many miles, giving a degenerate distribution with all probability on $x$. (Then there are some highways where it sure seems like there is nothing nearby!)

Comment: Locations won't be independent of each other and desirability and possibility of location are influenced by multiple things